# I have stored Table fields and Textbox values in two different list<string> now I want to use those lists in insert query how to do it?

Tags: c#, sql

I have stored Table fields and Textbox values in two different `list<string>`.

I want to use those lists in insert query how to do it ? and what about quotation marks if value is numeric ?

```
foreach (Control Txt_Name in TB_List) {
  String TxtName = Txt_Name.Text;
  String field_name = Txt_Name.Name.Substring(3);
  Field_Name.Add(field_name);
  TB_Name.Add(TxtName);
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into "+ Table_Name +
  "('"+ Field_Name + "') Values('" + TB_Name + "')", con);
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: foreach (Control Txt_Name in TB_List)
                    {
                        String TxtName = Txt_Name.Text;
                        String field_name = Txt_Name.Name.Substring(3);
                       
                        Field_Name.Add(field_name);
                       
                        TB_Name.Add(TxtName);
                    }
 

 

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into "+ Table_Name + "('"+ Field_Name + "') Values('" + TB_Name + "')", con);

Comment: I want to make method like this public void SaveRec(String Con_String, String Table_Name, Form Frm, int AddFlag, int EditFlag)

Comment: My field name and textbox names are same with just "Txt" suffix

Comment: Read up on SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Table field must be separated with commas.
Value field must be treated in different ways.
Example: String values want the single quote before and after the value, int doesn't..
The best way is to handle the insert statement with a sql procedure.

Comment: I want to make library so dont  want to fix any field or data !! I think in store procedure table fields are fixed for particular table !!